# What happens if my image is greater than maxSize for Firebase Storage?

Tags: swift, firebase-storage

I couldn't find the answer to this elsewhere. What happens if the image size is greater than maxSize for Firebase Storage?

For example, in my app, I store images on the server and the user can download them later, if desired. When I call the getData with the maxSize option set to *1 * 1024 * 1024*, I get the following error on a few of the images:

> Attempted to download object with size of 1059073 [example] bytes, which exceeds the maximum size of 1048576 bytes.

I get it... the photo is bigger than the maxSize I set. What I'm wanting to know is even though it's bigger than the maxSize, what happens? Does the image get compressed over and over until it finally meets the maxSize threshold and is then downloaded? Does the image get skipped all together and not downloaded because it's too large?

How can I compress the images to a small enough size when uploading? The solutions I've tried must be outdated, because they don't work very well. I know that's a separate question, but if you don't mind answering it as well then great... two birds with one stone - if not, then oh well.

The error says to "***Consider raising the maximum download size.***" How do I know how high I can raise it **without** slowing the app down or causing an issue??

Please explain your answers with code or a link!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm wanting to know is even though it's bigger than the maxSize, what happens?

The file does not get downloaded, as it's bigger than the maximum size you've reserved for it. Aside from that, nothing happens.

> Does the image get compressed over and over until it finally meets the maxSize threshold and is then downloaded?

Definitely not. Firebase Storage knows nothing about your files on its own, so it doesn't touch them in any way. There may be add-on products (such as Extensions) that can resize images, but those are not triggered by the condition you have.

If you're having trouble making a resizing solution work, open a new question with the [minimum steps with which anyone can reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I actually got it figured out, but I'll leave this post up for anyone else who may be asking the same question. Thanks for your help!!